# Check owner is msg.sender, but still gives ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved

Tags: solidity

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, even looking at other questions posted.
The token should be holding the nft

In the NFT contract,

```
function NFTMe(string memory tokenUR) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenUR);
        // setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true); <-- this will give me reverted with reason string 'ERC721: approve to caller'
        _tokenIds.increment();
        return newId ;
    }
```

I have another function to see who is the owner:

```
function getOwner(uint256 tokenId) public view returns(address) {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        return owner;
    }
```

When I deploy, it says currentOwner is the owner who minted it.

In the token,

```
constructor( string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address nftAddr) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
nft = IERC721(nftAddr);
}
function transfer() public {
    // 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'
    nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId); 
 }
```

Comment: Can you describe the expected result? Is your intention to mint the token to the user (in the `NFTMe()` function), and then transfer it from the user to the `token` contract (in the `transfer()` function)? Or something else?

Comment: @PetrHejda yes correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'
nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
```

In this case, the "transfer caller" is your `token` contract. Which is not the token owner, not approved by the user (the token owner) to transfer the token.

The easiest solution is to make the `token` contract automatically approved by the user from within the `NFTMe()` function in the `NFT` contract:

```
_approve(tokenContractAddress, newTokenId);
```

Comment: But in the token contract, it needs the input of the NFT token Id. If you look at the constructor of the token, it passes the NFT address. Seems like a chicken and egg?

Comment: @hammies You can set the `token` address in the `NFT` contract through a custom setter function after the `token` contract has been deployed... So the flow can be for example: 1) deploy `NFT` with empty `token` address value, 2) deploy `token` passing it the `NFT` address, 3) set the `token` address in `NFT`.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense!!